# How do you refer to custom javascript functions in your type script methods?

Tags: angular, typescript

Say, you have a simple Javascript function such as `sayHello()`:

```
function sayHello(){
   alert('Hello');
}
```

and you put this in your app's `assets/js` folder as a custom library `assets/js/my-js-library.js`

Then, finally, you refer to it from the `index.html` like this:

```
<script src='http://example.com/assets/js/my-js-library.js'></script>
```

What does it take in typescript  ( say in ngOnInit for example ) so you can do something like this?

```
ngOnInit () {
   sayHello();
}
```

Or is it not possible?

Comment: Yes your code should just work, did you try it? If a javascript function is in the global scope you can call it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can.

external.js

```
var myExtObject = (function() {

  return {
    func1: function() {
      alert('function 1 called');
    },
    func2: function() {
      alert('function 2 called');
    }
  }

    })(myExtObject||{})

function justAFunction(){
   alert('test');
}

var webGlObject = (function() { 
  return { 
    init: function() { 
      alert('webGlObject initialized');
    } 
  } 
})(webGlObject||{})
```

app.ts

```
import 'external.js'

declare var myExtObject: any;
declare var webGlObject: any;

export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    webGlObject.init();
    justAFunction();
  }

  CallFunction1() {
    myExtObject.func1();
  }

  CallFunction2() {
    myExtObject.func2();
  }
}
```

check out this URL : https://plnkr.co/edit/b2kAztHntMuNjTfOv8jD?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. if it is this much work, would you say that it is better to convert your js library functions into typeScript and by pass this method completely? Cause honestly, I wasnot expecting such a multiple step operation for a sayHello func which is bare js func anyway?

Comment: i updated the code, you can just directly call your js function after import the  external.js into your typescipt

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for your spending time on this - __this much__. Really appreciate it. To further simplify the code and exactly anser my question, I will create an answer. Would you please check and modify it if I make any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

external.js

```
function justAFunction(){
   alert('test');
}
```

app.ts

```
import 'external.js'

export class App {
  constructor() {
    justAFunction();
  }
}
```

would this work?
I assumed that the declaring of `webGlObject` has no bearing on the `justAFunction`. The reason I cut the code on the func1 and func2 cause I did not have business with the objects. I just wanted to see the bare bone necessity to make a simple external HelloWorld js function to be utilized within TypeScript.

If we just focused on the `justAFunction`, would this code be the min necessity? I guess my mistake was to use the `<Script src=''>` as opposed to the `import`, then. Yes, No?